# How to understand Objective-C AppDelegate method application:didFInishLauchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios

I am new in iOS development, I saw the function

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

As I know, to declare a function is

```
-/+(return type)function_name: (param type)param
```

So what is the function name of the function mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Here name of the function is application but its mostly called application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Its called first when the app is launched.